# Protractor - Verify that element exist

Tags: testing, protractor, end-to-end

i am using some kind of angular filter of a table and i need to verify if results from filter is correct.

I already work with this table before, where I click on element:

```
element.all(by.xpath('.//td[.="89" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).click();
```

this basicly click on element where `<td>` have value 89. I need to verify that this number is still there after I enter for example number 8 to filter So i write this:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath('.//td[.="89" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'isPresent'

I didn't find any other method how to verify if something exist, is there some problem in syntax or is there any other method which can replace isPresent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`isPresent`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent) is available only for `ElementFinder`, not for `ElementArrayFinder`, so you should not call it after you've used `all`:

```
expect(element(by.xpath('.//td[.="89" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

If you really want to use `all`, try with `count()` instead:

```
expect(element.all(by.xpath('.//td[.="89" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).count()).toBe(1);
```

Comment: Thank you :) i expect there will be problem but your explenation help me to understand this issue :)

Answer (score 1):

**I am not sure but i think u cannot have element.all(by.xpath(''));** 
so you can try::::

```
expect(element(by.xpath('.//td[.="89" and @class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

or choose different locator

```
expect(element.all(by.css('td[class="ultranarrow ng-binding"]')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Hi @Sohel Saiyed, I am able because I am using it for click on that element somewhere else, I am just not sure if I can use it with isPresent